# Prove $\mathcal M^\perp=\{g\in L^2(0,1) : g=\alpha \text{ a.e.p.}, \alpha\in\mathbb R \}$

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

I've been solving some problems from my functional analysis course and got stuck in certain question. The problem is longer, but i'll just post the question I can't solve:

> Given $\mathcal H=L^2((0,1))$ and $\mathcal M:=\left\{f\in\mathcal H:
>  \int_0^1f(x)dx=0\right\}$.
>
> Prove that $\mathcal M^\perp=\{g\in L^2(0,1) : g=\alpha \text{ a.e.p.},
>  \alpha\in\mathbb R \}$ (a.e.p. means in almost every point).

I've been able to prove just one contains the other, doing the following (considering the scalar product in $L^2(0,1)$):

If $g(x)=\alpha\equiv\text{real constant}$ in almost every point, then
$$\langle f,g\rangle = \int_0^1 \alpha f(x) dx=\alpha\int_0^1f(x)dx=0,$$
so then it's implied that $\{g\in L^2(0,1) : g=\alpha \text{ a.e.p.},
 \alpha\in\mathbb R \}\subseteq\mathcal M^\perp$.

How can I prove the opposite? To be said, that $\mathcal M^\perp\subseteq\{g\in L^2(0,1) : g=\alpha \text{ a.e.p.},
 \alpha\in\mathbb R \}$? Any help or hint will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $g \in M^{\perp}$. Let $f \in L^{1}$ and $c=\int_0^{1} f(x)dx$. Let $h=f-c$. Then  $h \in M$ so $\int gh=\int g(f-c)=0$. This gives $\int gf =c \int g$. Write this as $\int gf =\int f\int g$ or $\int gf =a\int f$ where $a=\int g$. So $\int f(g-a)=0$ for all $f \in L^{1}$. Can you finish?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer formulated in terms of Hilbert space techniques:

Note that
$$
\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx=\int_0^1 f(x)1\,dx=\langle f,1\rangle.
$$
In other words, $\mathcal M=\{1\}^\perp$. It is an elementary fact in Hilbert space theory that $\mathcal {V}^{\perp\perp}$ is the closed linear hull of $\mathcal V$. In this case, $\mathcal M^\perp$ is the closed linear hull of $\{1\}$, which is $\{\lambda 1\mid \lambda\in\mathbb R\}$, as desired (note that elements of $L^2$ are only determined a.e., so that $g=\lambda 1$ in $L^2$ if $g(x)=\lambda$ a.e.).